# PhpStorm: Reformat JavaScript without script tags

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, reformatting

In PhpStorm, when reformatting code, JavaScript gets placed to the left hand side of the page. Instead of using the standard script tags I use

```
<?php $this->startJs() ?>
// Javascript goes here
<?php $this->endJs() ?>
```

I've looked in settings -> editor -> Language Injections but can't figure out how to tell PhpStorm that the above starts and stops JavaScript so it can format it correctly.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way of injecting custom language in between ordinary PHP calls like you have got there. Language Injection rule needs an anchor point (where it it injects into, and that's a tag, attribute, any string .. but not "in between 2 ordinary php calls"). There are some possible workarounds (impractical though) but they require editing the code (e.g. use `echo <<<JS` .. or `include "file/with.js"` kind of stuff) but I know none where it would be possible with just editing a settings.

Comment: I agree with LazyOne. If you don't want to use `script src`, you may want to `include` the file.